# Can I create corresponding replicas in Docker Compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, replication

I am building an application which uses a number of Celery workers (which process tasks from a queue). The workers should run some scripts against a MySQL database, which is also containerized. Specifically, each worker should run its scripts on a *different* MySQL container. What I would like to know is whether I can create replicas of a clean MySQL container and make it so that worker replica 1 only tries to run scripts against MySQL replica 1, etc.

My current proof-of-concept starts up a new MySQL container from within the worker but this is a performance nightmare and it has security implications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer, yes you can create replicas of clean mysql containers, just name the services accordingly.

The caveat is you cannot share/access the data from one mysql container with another. And it would be better if you use different databases within single mysql container, that will be more performance friendly and easy to backup.

To share data between different mysql containers, all you need is setup mysql master slave.

Comment: Hadn't considered the possibility of separate services! Yes, that should do it. I want the MySQL containers to be isolated from one another. There is a constraint in place that would make it hard to use a single database. Thanks!